# Copy byte array to another byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

There are two byte arrays which are populated with different values.

```
byte[] Array1 = new byte[5];
byte[] Array2 = new byte[5];
```

Then, I need `Array1` to get exactly the same values as `Array2`.

By typing `Array1 = Array2` I would just set references, this would not copy the values.

What might be the solution?

**EDIT:**

All answers are good and all solutions work. The code from the first solution looks visually more descriptive for my particular case.

> Array1 = Array2.ToArray();

and

> Array1.CopyTo(Array2, 0);

as well as

> Buffer.BlockCopy(Array2, 0, Array1, 0, 5);

Comment: Investigate [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Bytes from a byte array to a specific position of another Byte array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887421/copy-bytes-from-a-byte-array-to-a-specific-position-of-another-byte-array-in-c-s)

Comment: No, the first array should be an exact copy of the second. But it should not be linked in any way with it. Should not be a pointer.

Comment: "Both answers are good and both solutions work". As well as `Buffer.BlockCopy` mentioned in the first comment, any [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, [Array.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

One solution courtesy of Linq...

```
Array1 = Array2.ToArray();
```

EDIT: you do not need to allocate space for Array1 before using this Linq call.  The allocation for `Array1` is done within `ToArray()`.  More complete example below

```
byte[] Array2 = new byte[5];
// set values for Array2
byte[] Array1 = Array2.ToArray();
```

Comment: This is a fairly neat solution, but since the OP has allocated the destination array already **and** has said, "I just set references, I don't copy the values", then I think it would be prudent to point out in your answer that you are creating a new reference and not copying the values to the pre-allocated array.

Comment: Will do, the statement in the OP "By typing `Array1 = Array2` I just set references, I don't copy the values" I thought was an attempt to say that the array reference was copied, and that the values themselves were not duplicated.  This also seemed to be the case in his later comment "But it should not be linked in any way with it.", which I thought was an attempt to say `Array1[0] = (byte) 1` will do nothing to the values in `Array2`

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I think your answer is a fairly neat solution. I just thought that the OP might need to understand the mechanics a little more deeply.

Comment: As I understood, `Array2.ToArray()` allocates a new array. What if `Array1 = Array2.ToArray();` is executed multiple times, in a for loop for example? Does these allocations remain in memory?

Comment: @acoder C# has a garbage collection system, so if you have no more references to allocated memory, then the values will be cleaned up. I wouldn't recommend allocating new memory in a loop just to ignore the values quickly thereafter.

Answer (score 48):

```
Array2.CopyTo(Array1, 0);
```

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto)

Comment: Six years later, I feel it's worth pointing out that this should be `Array2.CopyTo(Array1, 0)`. The line as given does the copy in the opposite direction to what was asked.

Comment: @Kemp, yep, fixed.

Comment: A little more details would've been helpful. The integer parameter is from which element it should copy. Microsoft docs are unreadable as always. I believe Array1 needs to be pre-allocated, I'll find out soon enough :-)