# Unity Hololens Crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, hololens

I am coding an application that uses the camera using Unity and the Hololens. It works ok. Then I changed something (explained later) and I got the following errors after a crash:

> d3d11: failed to create staging 2D texture w=896 h=504 d3dfmt=87 [887a0005]
>
> d3d11: failed to lock buffer 1104C69C of size 4194304 [0x8007000E].
>
> DrawBuffers() got a range of indices but no index buffer   (Filename:
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/DrawBuffersD3D11.cpp
>   Line: 137)

I have searched for these errors and there are no solutions applicable. I hope I could get some insights on this.

---

**What I was doing and what I changed**

Basically the program acquired a frame from the camera in a array of bytes `byte[] _latestImage;`
Originally this image is applied to a Texture as in

```
_videoTexture.LoadRawTextureData(_latestImage);
_videoTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
_videoTexture.Apply();
_videoPanelUIRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", _videoTexture);
```

where `_videoTexture` is a Texture2D and `_videoPanelUIRenderer` is a Renderer.

This works right. Then I processed the array _latestImage to convert it to Grey inside a function `ProcessSync`. This also works right with the only problem: Since the array is being processed (into Grey) but *also* is being updated automatically by the camera, when applying into a texture, it flickers, sometimes grey, and sometimes in color. But other than that, no crash.

So my next step was to *Clone* that array at the start of the processing function so that I can process this new array and apply it to a texture without the interference of new data coming from the camera.

so I did:

```
 void ProcessSync(byte[] rawimage, Matrix4x4 cTwMatrix, Matrix4x4 pMatrix)
    {
        int rr, gg, bb;
        int p = 0;
        int yval;
        byte[] image=(byte[])rawimage.Clone();//<--THIS is the only change

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
              { //...some processing here
               }

       //Then apply it to the texture like indicated above
}
```

When I apply this, the application works fine, and I can see that I am getting the grey image...but after some time it crashes with the message above.

My image is 896x504 so I guess

> d3d11: failed to create staging 2D texture w=896 h=504 d3dfmt=87
>   [887a0005]

means that somehow the Texture2D failed to be created but why? My texture is only created once when the video mode is being initialized so I don't understand why this happens.

I guess the error could be related with me cloning the image. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I'm sure with arrays that `.Clone()` returns a shallow copy even if the contained objects are value types. It's probably that `rawimage` is manipulated or disposed which then causes the issue with it's copy. You could look at making a deep copy instead. I'm not 100% hence a comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Equalsk mentioned in comment, there might be chances that the original array is being reused (considering that Array is a reference type). One thing you can do is to create a copy of array before passing in the `ProcessSync()` leaving no chance of the original pointer being used in the method.

One more thing I would suggest : Method should have single responsibility (return the processed array). The resulting `byte[]` should be then applied to texture.

```
byte[] ProcessSync(byte[] image, Matrix4x4 cTwMatrix, Matrix4x4 pMatrix)
{
    int rr, gg, bb;
    int p = 0;
    int yval;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
          { //...some processing here
           }
    return image;
}
```

Then use it as following:

```
var image = ProcessSync(_latestImage.ToArray(),_cTwCatrix, _pMatrix);

_videoTexture.LoadRawTextureData(image);
_videoTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
_videoTexture.Apply();
_videoPanelUIRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", _videoTexture);
```

NOTE: `ToArray()` is extension from `System.Linq` which creates a copy. You can use [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833713/copy-byte-array-to-another-byte-array-in-c-sharp) to copy the array if you prefer.

Hope this helps :)