# Translate from c# to Powershell - Pointers

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to translate this piece of code from C# to Powershell.

```
static unsafe void Copy(IntPtr source, int sourceOffset, IntPtr destination, int destinationOffset, int count)
{
    byte* src = (byte*)source + sourceOffset;
    byte* dst = (byte*)destination + destinationOffset;
    byte* end = dst + count;

    while (dst != end)
        *dst++ = *src++;
}
```

I' dont know how to deal with pointers in Powershell
Can anybody help me?

Comment: More context is needed. Why do you think you even *need* this code in PowerShell? Note that you can always port C# code in its entirety using `Add-Type` (with `-CompilerParameters` to pass `/unsafe` to compile unsafe code), but there's possibly a better solution that requires no unsafe code at all. (For completeness: PowerShell has no native pointer types.)

Comment: doesn't this just do an array copy?...you can use the original byte array and do a copy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833713/copy-byte-array-to-another-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: I assume this is to do with low-level graphics etc.? otherwise you can just do a straight array copy, if you're trying to do low level programming powershell really shouldn't be your tool of choice - but as Jeroen said you can compile unsafe code directly into Powershell types.

Comment: Thank you all for anwswer so fast. What i am trying to do, is a module that reads a folder full of font files and reads one by one, renders the font and creates a file either BMP or JPG. . I'm using as Sharpfont https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont to render the font file. In this  files there is an example that has this piece of code.

Comment: And, yes this piece of code is related to low level graphics.